# How to create a mutable jbutton array

Tags: java, jbutton, mutable

Im trying to create a mutable array of Jbuttons. The amount of JButtons depends on the user's preferences. I dont know what im doing wrong here.
Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class e {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<JButton> students = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        students.add(new JButton());
        JButton.setSize(100,100);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I dont want to make a separate Jbutton and then add it to the array. I want the array to be able to add buttons and then i can change it by calling its place in the array EX: students[0]

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<JButton> students = new ArrayList<JButton>();
students.add(new JButton());
JButton.setSize(100,100);
```

`setSize()` is not a static function of `JButton` class hence you will have to access with the object instance of `JButton`. You probably wanted to do this:

```
   ArrayList<JButton> students = new ArrayList<JButton>();
   JButton button = new JButton();
   button.setSize(100,100);
   students.add(button);
```

But i am quite curious what intended to do by setting the size hint with `setSize` method, unless your intention is to work with `null layout`, off-course, `null layout` is no go.

Answer (score 0):

executing `JButton.setSize` is executing static method (not sure if such exists though), but you want to execute that on instance of `JButton` like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class e {
public static void main(String args[]){
ArrayList<JButton> students = new ArrayList<JButton>();
JButton jb = new JButton();
students.add(jb);
jb.setSize(100,100);
}

}
```